# How to make radio station of 100 track using php

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, http-live-streaming, shoutcast, icecast

I have `100 Tracks` on my `AWS Server`. I want to make `Radio Station` of these `100 Track`. my site is made in php.

**Few Examples:**

http://www.radiotunes.com/smoothbeats

https://cdn.prahec.com/projects/radio-player/player/

Comment: can you please post what you tried or anything which you did to achieve ?

Comment: user1140237 i need to make radio of 100 tracks. i didn't code for it.I mentioned example of radio. I asked how i can make radio like given example using php

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to achieve. On one hand you say PHP and on the other hand you imply that you want to use Icecast?

Comment: Also, jftr and from personal experience. 100 tracks makes for a horrible brainwash rotation. You'll need closer to a thousand to not be very annoying.

Comment: can you please suggest me how i can play 100 tracks on my server so that all user access/listen  same track at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need:

- run Icecast (as of time of writing 2.4.2 is the latest version, with [packages for most distributions](https://wiki.xiph.org/Icecast_Server/Installing_latest_version_(official_Xiph_repositories))).
- a source client that takes the files and encodes them into a continuous stream.
  E.g. mpd, ezstream, xmms2

  - please note that the file format and the stream codec have **no relation** and using a free codec like Opus as the primary stream is highly recommended.
- A HTML5 player on your website that points to your stream

Comment: Thanks TBR for your support

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this forum will help you

```
http://forums.nexusmods.com/index.php?/topic/274194-tutorial-how-to-create-a-new-radio-station/
```